# In LyX, how can I nest Itemize inside Enumerate, without starting a new Enumerate item when leaving Itemize?

Tags: lyx, enumerate, itemize, nesting

What I'm trying to accomplish in LyX is best shown via the following simple example:

1. I start using
2. an Enumerate environment

   And I'm writing multiple blocks of text, even tables, etc., inside the enumerated item (this part is easy w/ Ctrl+Enter)

   - then I switch to Itemize
   - to list some things
   - I do this using Alt+Shift+Right
   - and then selecting "Itemize" environment

   Eventually I am done with Itemize, and I write some additional text (or tables, etc.), remaining on the same enumerated item as when I started Itemize

   (This bit right here is what I cannot seem to get LyX to do)
3. Finally, I move on to another item. When I want to... not right after Itemize ends.

This is something that I can accomplish easily with HTML (or Markdown/CommonMark): just an unordered list inside an ordered list item.

I *did* find a workaround for this by inserting TeX code `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` while inside the Enumerate item.

But I do this often and it *seems* like this kind of thing would be a fully-supported in LyX that I'm somehow missing.

Comment: Are you after using Alt + Shift + Left to go one level up in the list structure, and then either Alt + P, E or clicking the numbered list-button on the toolbar to make it part of the enumerate? (I.e. exactly opposite of what you did to start the itemize.)

Comment: Yes, that is what I had been trying. However, going back into the enumerate environment creates a new item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I have a general idea. This might be better as a comment, but I wanted to add some images so I've chucked this together as an answer.

**My work flow using enumerate/itemize in LyX**

- Starting a new list: `Alt + P E` (press the `Alt` and `P` keys together, then press `E`) [1, 2, 3, ...]
- Adding a new item: `Enter` / `Return` key
- Start a sub list: `Enter` (start a new item) then either

  1. `Tab` to "indent" the list [a, b, c, ...]
  2. `Alt + Shift + Right Arrow` (achieves the same result, but less touch type friendly imho)
- Return to the main list: `Enter` (start  a new item) then either:

  1. `Shift + Tab` to "unindent" the list  to get back to [2, 3, 4, ...]
  2. `Alt + Shift + Left Arrow` (same opinion, slows me down imho)
- Indenting content without leaving enumerate either:

  1. `Ctrl + Enter` to use line breaks, `\\` in source `LaTeX`, to manually break the list item into multiple lines. Works alright for basic content e.g. text as you've probably noticed.
  2. Multiple `Enter` or `Alt + Enter` to start a new line that is *not* enumerate (i.e. standard) then use `Tab` or `Alt + Shift + Right Arrow` to indent it "into" the enumerate environment required.

     To  stay in this indent environment use `Alt + Enter` to start new lines. In `LyX` you can see this by the large red braces `[` on the left hand side.

**Example**
[image: Enumerate in LyX]

Note that I always work with code shown and the way to do it is `View > Source Pane`. I just find it helps especially if you've come from `LaTeX`.

If I could I would point you to some documentation for this but I learnt `LaTeX` before I learnt `LyX` and I've mainly learnt these shortcuts from trial and error. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, re-creating your sample document I was able to acheive the effect that I wanted. Not sure I really grok what the tab is doing... feels a bit like emacs tab indending. In any case, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Perhaps I need to spend more time reading the manual/tutorial.